# Reading .doc file using win32com.client.Dispatch()

Tags: python

I'm attempting to read a .doc file's text into python using this:

```
doc_ex = root_folder+"/"+"GS-35F-309AA_A02 -SOW microsoft Dynamic 365.doc"
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = False
wb = word.Documents.Open(doc_ex)
doc = word.ActiveDocument
docText = doc.Content.Text
print(docText)
```

and I'm getting this error message:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?\r (C:\\//Users/MBS/TheFolder_MS...)", 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
```

It looks like python is doing something funky with the path I provide it. This is what the path doc_ex looks like:

```
doc_ex
Out[12]: 'C:/Users/MBS/TheFolder_MS/Work/IT_Contracts/MIke_Clean/GS-35F-309AA_A02 -SOW microsoft Dynamic 365.doc'
```

The system adds that \// stuff to the path and of course cannot find it because that's not the path. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Also, don't know if it matters but root_folder is declared like this:

```
root_folder = r"C:/Users/MBS/TheFolder_MS/Work/IT_Contracts/MIke_Clean"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `os.path.join()` instead.

e.g.

```
import os
doc_ex = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Users', 'MBS', 'TheFolder_MS', 'Work', 'IT_Contracts', 'MIke_Clean', "GS-35F-309AA_A02 -SOW microsoft Dynamic 365.doc")
```

If you want to make sure Python finds the file you could add:

```
if os.path.exists(doc_ex):
    print('%s exists' % doc_ex)
```

Comment: That did not work Alexis. Thanks for the attempt. And yes, python says the path exists. The problem lies in that \\// added by the function call. How do I make it stop adding that? I'm assuming that's the problem; I don't see what else it could be?

Answer (score 0):

The below works. I had to reverse the direction of the slashes and add a double slash at the end.

```
root_folder2 = r"C:\Users\MBS\TheFolder_MS\Work\IT_Contracts\MIke_Clean\\"
doc_ex = os.path.join(root_folder2, "GS-35F-309AA_A02 -SOW microsoft Dynamic 365.doc")
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.visible = False
wb = word.Documents.Open(doc_ex)
doc = word.ActiveDocument
docText = doc.Content.Text
print(docText)
```